# How to write ^C in the Windows console?

Tags: windows, windows-console

How to write ^C at in the Windows console? For example, I need to enter ^C in [this window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGwfS.png). If you press Ctrl+C in the console, the application exits and the console closes.

Comment: Can't you write it as two separate symbols?

Comment: You mean you want to know the key sequence to enter that `^C` appears in the console?

Comment: I need this no two separate symbols

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/ctrl-c-and-ctrl-break-signals (in an app written by you yourself).

Comment: this isn't  c++ code

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ this is what I need in c++ cmd terminal

Comment: Why did you choose that tag then?

Comment: what can I choose?

Comment: type `^` (nothing appears on screen), then type `C` (`^C` appears)

Comment: This question has nothing to do with the CMD shell. You're running an executable named sdfdsf.exe that's attached to a console window. This window is hosted by an instance of the console host process. In Windows 7+, the console host is conhost.exe. In older versions it's hosted in csrss.exe. The client process, sfddsf.exe, uses the Windows console API (e.g. `GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo`) and standard I/O (e.g. `ReadFile`, `WriteFile`) to interact with the console. In Windows 8+, console I/O is implemented using the condrv.sys device driver. In older versions it uses an [A]LPC port.

Answer (score 0):

If you press CTRL+C to cancel the execution of command in cmd

Answer (score 0):

In your keyboard SHIFT+6 = ^

then you can use ^C as a string in the cmd